# Find and Replace NumberLong type field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update some NumberLong type value in one of my collection with some other NumberLong value. Below is my collection structure :

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e57337d4c6cf80e68b1fe3"),
    "tenantId" : NumberLong(7),
    "refId" : NumberLong(20),
    "refIdentifierName" : "resourceInstanceId",
    "config" : {
        "contract" : {
            "contractLength" : "12 months",
            "startDate" : "2015-01-21T09:36:39+00:00",
            "billingFrequency" : "monthly",
            "margin" : 9,
            "endDate" : "2016-01-21T09:36:39+00:00"
        }

}
```

Lets say here i am trying to update all tenantId with value 7 to 8.

This is the script i am using :

```
 var cursor = db.resourceInstanceConfiguration.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var x = cursor.next();
  x['tenantId'] = x['tenantId'].replace('7','8');
  db.resourceInstanceConfiguration.update({_id : x._id}, x);
}
```

Getting error : `TypeError: Object NumberLong(6) has no method 'replace'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do achieve this by using the following query:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)

db.collectionName.update({<field>:<value>},{$set:{<field>:<New Value>}},<upsert>,<multi>);
```

Comment: I would feel fortunate for the votes if I were you as this really is not much more than a listing from the documentation of options and is also a completely incorrect answer to the question asked.

Comment: Well..This works!! db.resourceInstanceConfiguration.update({"tenantId":NumberLong(7)},{$set:{"tenantId":NumberLong(8)}},false,true)

Answer (score 3):

Seems some people were very quick to upvote another answer without realizing it cannot possibly work, nor is it a very good explanation.

The two problems here are that you basically need to "loop" the results in order to read the values you want to change and then write them back. This is probably best handled with ["Bulk" operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) and best done under the shell as a one of script.

The "next" problem is the BSON type information here is "sticky" and that you cannot simply change the value to an plain double in code and write it back. You need to actually "remove" the field completely from the document "before" you can write back a converted value.

Again the whole process lends well to bulk operations as follows:

```js
var bulk = db.resourceInstanceConfiguration.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.junk.find({ 
    "$or": [
        { "tenantId": { "$type": 18 } },
        { "refId": { "$type": 18 } }
    ]            
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    print(doc.a.valueOf());
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$unset": { "tenantId": "", "refId": "" }
    });
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { 
            "tenantId": doc.tenantId.valueOf(),
            "refId": doc.tenantId.valueOf()
        }
    });
    count += 2;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.resourceInstanceConfiguration.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }

});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

So you essentially [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) first to remove all trace for the BSON data for the field and the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) with the new value.

All values will then be a standard "double" or BSON type 1 as also confirmed by the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator.

Comment: Hey thanks for the accurate explanation , though the answer given by Kartikey worked for me !!  tried this :   db.resourceInstanceEvent.update({"refId":NumberLong(7)},{$set:{"refId":NumberLong(8)}},false,true);

Comment: @RahulBGangwar Well if all you want to do is just "replace everything" with a standard number then it's going to work. Guess it really was a misread of your question then, as people do ask what is shown here of `NumberInt` to `Double` But I still say that merely quoting documentation is an attrocious excuse for an answer. Personally I would not encourage someones ability to use a search engine.